# MVC Payment provider

Tags: security, model-view-controller, payment, payment-processing

After two week I will publish my website on productions.Web site is a e commerce.I have two way of payments:

1. Pay pal
2. Pay on delivery

I want to make 3th payment method that looks like this one[image: payment-method].
My question is : Is there a come kind of web api or providder that give me to redirct on payment procces like picture where users is redirect and can secure fills theirs data.My project is on MVC !

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 3 partialViews and 3 viewModels for each payment method. Then set required attribute to your viewModel's properties.

```
[Required("CreditCard_Field_Required_Error")]
[StringLength(16)]
public string CreditCardNumber { get; set; }
```

And check which model and view is filled on button click with jquery.

The other way is post your data with Ajax.ActionLink and get the result of view which you send to related controller.

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("menu list",
                 "GetCardResultInfo",
                 new AjaxOptions{
                                 InsertionMode=InsertionMode.Replace,
                                 UpdateTargetId="CardPayment",
                                 HttpMethod="GET",

                 })

<div id="CardPayment"></div>
```